# Android List Item with Image View not clickable

Tags: android, android-listview

I have an List Item with `ImageView`'s, `TextView`'s. Issue is List Item as whole is not clickable, it's only when I click on any of the `ImageView` it's clickable. I have set `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` for root and below for each child

```
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

Still only `ImageViews` are clickable. Below is my list item xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://splashurl.com/m22ydvb
    android:id="@+id/itemdisplaylist_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    android:minHeight="@dimen/loclist_item_minumum_height"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/listitem_pic"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.7"
        android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="1" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/listitem_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.3"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:textColor="@color/loclistitem_text"
            android:textIsSelectable="true" >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/listitem_address"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:textIsSelectable="true" >
        </TextView>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/listitem_text2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.4"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                android:textColor="@color/loclistitem_text"
                android:textIsSelectable="true" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/listitem_prop1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.2"
                android:contentDescription="@null"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="false" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/listitem_prop2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.2"
                android:contentDescription="@null"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="false" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/listitem_prop3"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.2"
                android:contentDescription="@null"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="false" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/listitem_img3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.1"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false" 
        android:clickable="false"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

I am not sure where I am going wrong but struggling for last 6 hours.

Custom Adapter Code(Partial Coe):

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_listitem, parent,false);

            holder.locName = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.listitem_name);
            holder.locDistance = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.listitem_text2);

            holder.locRating = (ImageView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.listitem_img3);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {

            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

        }
        convertView.setOnClickListener(this);

        holder.locName.setText(data.get(position).getLocationName());

        return convertView;
```

Please advise.

```
Solution
```

Finally I was able to do this by using Relative Layout instead of Linear Layout in my list item layout.

Comment: try `convertView.setOnClickListener(....)` on `getView` method and remove `setOnItemClickListener` form activity

Comment: Thanks for reply. I had tried this earlier and now again as suggested. Still same issue. When I click on ImageView its going on onClick method. On TextView click no response.

Comment: Are you using the view holder pattern?

Comment: Post your custom adapter code.

Comment: @Tareq : Ye I am using holder pattern

Comment: remove all `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` and try again with my suggest, if not helped post adapter class too

Comment: @shayanpourvatan Tried as suggested. Removed android:descendantFocusability but still same issue. I didn't remove android:focusable though. Edited the post with adapter code.

Comment: @Tareq Edited my post with Custom Adapter Code

Comment: did you remove onItemClick too? if yes please clean your project because in my look everything is fine

Comment: @shayanpourvatan : Yes I removed list.setOnItemClickListener from Main Activity. Cleaned the project and tried again. Unfortunately still same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Add the click listener when you inflate the view only. Try this:

```
convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_listitem, null);

convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {



                }

            });
  convertView.setTag(holder);
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. Tried as suggested and still same issue. Only Image View Click is working.

Comment: Try the code while removing: android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"

Comment: Also try setting the OnClickListener on holder.locName

Comment: Tried this too. Still No luck. Seems like not my day today :)

Comment: Put this line in the constructor: LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

Comment: Thanks for being there and providing valuable suggestions. Tried this too but still stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this on your Activity class:

```
listView.setItemsCanFocus(true);
```

or

```
listView.setItemsCanFocus(false);
```

which is useful for you.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Tried as suggested. Still no luck. Same issue

Answer (score 0):

I know its late but may be someone finds it helpful. In order to make the whole item as clickable instead of different items in a row use this

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        }
    });
```